# Bundling dylibs, headerpad_max_install_names not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle, libraries

I have another OSX application problem. I want to bundle in my final application several dylibs, all of them needed by the application and by other dylibs.

I change its references using the install_name_tool, but some of the libraries couldn't be changed properly, having this error:

install_name_tool: changing install names or rpaths can't be redone for: aLibrary.dylib (for architecture x86_64) because larger updated load commands do not fit (the program must be relinked, and you may need to use -headerpad or -headerpad_max_install_names)

So I added the headerpad_max_install_names option flag on the linker flags of the xcode project (Project Properties-Build Settings-Linking-Other Linker Flags). Also I verified in the build log, if the option flag was included, and the option flag was included properly.

But still having the same error in the last dylibs.

Is there any way to bundle all the libraries needed in a unique Framework? Or am I doing something wrong in the building process?

Hope I'm clear with the main problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, using C++ and Code::Blocks, and I fixed it by switching from g++ to clang++